# Difference between plugins in project->build->pluginManagement and project->build

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, pom.xml

A snippet of my `pom` looks something like:

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-alpha-7</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
                <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <updateDependencies>true</updateDependencies>
                <generateBackupPoms>false</generateBackupPoms>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>
```

Can anybody explain the difference between the `<plugins>` listing under `project->build->pluginManagement` and `project->build`>?

Answer (score 3):

From the POM documentation at http://maven.apache.org/pom.html

> pluginManagement: is an element that is seen along side plugins. Plugin Management contains plugin elements in much the same way,
>   except that rather than configuring plugin information for this
>   particular project build, it is intended to configure project builds
>   that inherit from this one. However, this only configures plugins that
>   are actually referenced within the plugins element in the children.
>   The children have every right to override pluginManagement
>   definitions.